# Create a new dictonary based on keys and values of two different dictonaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two large dictionaries:
zip2state and zip2pop

both have zip codes as keys and the first has state abbreviations as values where the other has populations in that zip code as values.

Ex:

zip2pop
{99628 : 104 .....

I am tasked with creating a new dictionary that totals all the populations in a certain state and make the abbreviations the key with total populations as the value

I've tried a few things but nothing seems to even be close to working, any help?

Edit:
Sorry I messed up the example, in the zip2state is has different zip codes as the keys and the state abbreviations as the values

zip2state
{99628 : 'AK' ,.....

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, given these sample inputs:

```
zip2pop = {99628: 104, 99629: 9242, 99638: 5524, 99618: 89, 99648: 6502}
zip2state = {99628: 'AK', 99629: 'AK', 99638: 'WA', 99618: 'WA', 99648: 'OR'}

state2pop = {}
for z, s in zip2state.items():
    if s in state2pop:
        state2pop[s] += zip2pop[z]
    else:
        state2pop[s] = zip2pop[z]
```

Yields:

```
{'AK': 9346, 'WA': 5613, 'OR': 6502}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through the keys of one and values of another.

```
state2pop = dict()

for state, pop in zip2state.keys(), zip2pop.values():
    state2pop[state] = pop
```

If the zip2state does actually have the zipcode as keys, then you could replace `zip2state.keys()` with `zip2state.values()`.